# Self Join Help, only have one table to work with

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

My requirement is to find the manager (two levels up) from a worker of a certain role, and see if that person matches the leader.  I have one single table to work with - data example below.

| workerid | role | managerid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Associate | 5 |
| 2 | Associate | 5 |
| 3 | Leader | 6 |
| 4 | Leader | 6 |

I have done a self join but not sure if I'm getting the right results

```
select
    distinct t1.[workerid] as associateID,
    t1.[role] as assocaiteRole,
    t1.[managerid] as associateManagerID,
    t2.[managerid] as associateManagerLevel2ID,
    t2.[workerid] as leaderID,
    t2.[role] as managerRole,
    case WHEN t2.[workerid] = t2.[managerid] then 'bad' ELSE 'good' END AS result
FROM
    myTable t1
    JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.[managerid] = t2.[workerid]
WHERE
    t1.[role] = 'Associate'
    and t2.[role] = 'Leader'
```

I'm getting the correct managerLevel2.  In every case however, I'm getting the managerid = worker which I don't think is correct.

Results: in this case row 1 would fit the criteria, as leaderid = managerlevel2

| associateid | associaterolerole | associatemanagerid | associatemanagerLevel2id | leaderid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Associate | 5 | 7 | 7 |
| 2 | Associate | 5 | 7 | 9 |
| 3 | Associate | 6 | 7 | 10 |
| 4 | Associate | 6 | 8 | 11 |

Comment: show us your expected result as well

Comment: `not sure if I'm getting the right results`. This is the question you need to answer yourself. We does not know what do you want

Comment: _find the manager (two levels up) from a worker_ But your code does not "look" up 2 levels, does it? It only does a single self-join which I interpret as "one level".

Comment: I have added results.  Two levels is maybe confusing.  It's basically the "manager's manager'.  The full dataset has all workers and all managers.  So the self join gives me the managers manager of the worker.

Comment: based on your criteria `ON t1.[managerid] = t2.[workerid]` leaderid is always associateManagerID . so Its not clear what are you trying to do , also desired output should be based on the sample data .

Comment: I'm a little lost.  The manager ids are not in the sample data.  Yet you say that you have only one table.  Your question refers to "the leader" and the data has two leaders.

Comment: I'd love to know why you've thrown a `distinct` in there. Usually an indication of badly thought out joins

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is to find the manager (two levels up) from a worker of a certain role, and see if that person matches the leader.

Based on this description, you want two joins.  To return the rows that match this condition:

```
select t.*, tm.role, tmm.role
from mytable t join
     mytable tm
     on tm.workerid = t.managerid join
     mytable tmm
     on tmm.workerid = tm.managerid
where t.role = 'Associate' and tmm.role = 'Leader';
```